# Is it safe to assume all web-enabled devices have access to localhost/loopback/127.0.0.1 - even with "networking" turned off?

Tags: android, ios, windows, network-programming, localhost

I'm working on a project that I'd like to work offline.

Now it turns out that a major piece of infrastructure I'd like to use abstracts a major component only via a webservice.

I can provide all the data needed for the webservice in the local filesystem and make my own abstraction between it and the piece of infrastructure I mention.

Ideally I would've liked it if an abstraction had been made just as a regular object with methods that I could provide but the people behind it are only interested in the serverside case running on Unix-like operating systems where network access is a given.

They have recommended the best way for me to interface with it is to make my own webservice which implements the same functionality as a small locally running server on `localhost`.

But I'd like my project to be able to run on any devices including Windows, Android, and iOS.

**Is it true that I can expect all these environments to be able to connect to a local server on `localhost` even when they have "networking" turned off?**

I put scare quotes around "networking" because I don't own a smartphone or tablet but I know there is a deal of foolproofing to protect nontechnical users from malware, etc. Laptops often have a switch or hotkey to turn Wi-Fi and other networking on/off so I assume other devices do too and I assume they may not all work the same. Maybe some turn off just Wi-Fi while others might disable all networking at a low level ...

<sup>(I understand if it's decided to move this question to Programmers or Superuser but I see it as a programming problem so I'm asking on Stackoverflow.)</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Among the platforms you mentioned, only Windows has the ability to use localhost with wireless and all ethernet adapters turned off. You would have to install Microsoft's Loopback Adapter, which is one of the optional components you can get to from Add/Remove Programs. iOS does not offer a loopback option, and I don't know if Android does either.

Comment: iOS doesn't offer loopback? *really*? I'm curious as to why that is; I can imagine a few scenarios when such a feature would be useful.